# Angular2 CanActivate from beta to current RC3

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement in Angular2, the Auth0 login method from this [video](https://youtu.be/n4gSXwVDkSw?t=8m15s). He is also using `angular2-jwt`.

I read the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard), tried to implement it, but i can't get it right.
I tried `export class NavbarComponent implements CanActivate`,   `routerCanActivate(){}`, `canActivate(){}`. I'm stuck.

What changes are needed for **CanActivate**  to work in current RC3?

```
import {CanActivate} from 'angular2/router';
import {tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper} from 'angular2-jwt'; 
...    
@CanActivate (()=>tokenNotExpired())
export class NavbarComponent{
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-deactivate-deactivate

Create a service class that acts as guard:

> ```
> import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
>
> export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
>   canActivate() {
>     console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
>     return true;
>   }
> }
> ```

In the new router this now supports dependency injection out of the box

Configure the route to use that guard:

> ```
> {
>   path: 'admin',
>   component: CrisisAdminComponent,
>   canActivate: [AuthGuard]
> },
> ```

The guard service can also return an observable that resolves to true or false

> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
>
> import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
> import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
>
> @Injectable()
> export class AuthService {
>   isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
>
>   login() {
>     return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = true);
>   }
>
>   logout() {
>     this.isLoggedIn = false;
>   }
> }
> ```

The guard service needs to be provided as any other service.
A good place would be for example `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

```
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes),
  AuthGuard
];
```

Comment: @Gunter I remember trying the AuthGuard to in `app.routes.ts`  `import {AuthGuard} from './auth.guard'` , `canActivate: [AuthGuard] ` , but i get the same error : ` No provider for AuthGuard!`. I know how to add a provider in a Component, but i don't know how to add it in a service or a guard. What am i missing?

Comment: I don't know how exactly you initialize the router. I updated my answer with an example (at the end of the answer)

Comment: I think the router is initializing in main.ts : `bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ...  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS  ,])` is this what u ment?

Comment: Exactly. If you use it this way, then add `AuthGuard` to `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` like shown at the end of my answer.

Comment: Anyone had issues using `Http` from within `AuthService`? I get `No provider for Http! (AuthGuard -> AuthService -> Http)`

Comment: Did you provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS`?

Comment: Ah, I was providing my router and `AuthService` one level above the component I was providing `HTTP_PROVIDERS` and my other services in. Obviously router and `AuthService` wouldn't have had access. Duh! :)

Comment: I had to add **AuthenticationService** along with the **AuthGuard** to get ride of the "No provider..." error