# How to add token header in every angular2 router navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, oauth-2.0

I user angular2 rc.3 、router-3.0.0-alpha.8 and OAuth2 ,

I use OAuth2 ,so after logged in ,How to angular2 front carry token header to navigate other component each time

```
const APP_ROUTES:RouterConfig = [
   {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
   {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
   {path: 'user', component: UserComponent}

];
```

e.g. when i want to navigate to the protected  **'admin'** page , using **this.router.navigate(['/admin']);**

Comment: What do you mean by "add the access-token to router-config" or "add access-token in the header"?

Comment: assume **'admin'** page is a protected page , navigate to it needs**'access-token'** header ,  How can i set it in the router config

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096475/angular2-canactivate-from-beta-to-current-rc3/38096551#38096551

Comment: but above implemts didn't add the access-token to the request head . so if refresh the page ,it will respond 401

Comment: No idea what request you are talking about.

Comment: so the `templateUrl` is pointing at a page/partial page from an asp.net mvc controller / php / some sort of protected directory which requires some sort of authorization to be available?

Comment: if yes. The second solution Extending `BaseRequestOptions` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request might be what you are after. I have not tried it and not sure if the cache provider gets it this way.

Comment: I use OAuth2 ,so after logged in ,front needs carrying token header to navigate other component each time .

Comment: @Matthew i use `class MyRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions` but when router navigate to protected component , token didn't be added .

Comment: Did you include (in bootstrap):  `provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: MyRequestOptions })` ? If that didnt work it was a interesting guess.